# antd autocomplete dropdown height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

i'm new with antd, english is not my mother language so there is maybe mistakes, i have two question, 1: at the moment if there is much information in dropdown user wont know if there is more or not, need to scroll down(on mobile phones) to scrollbar appear, my question is how to have scrollbar visible all the time ? 2: if i dont want the first one, how to show 100% of dropdown without users having to scroll down ,for example 'listHeight' to be 100% (tried writing it there, wont accept %)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { CloseOutlined } from "@ant-design/icons";

export default function EventsSection() {
  const autoControl = React.createRef();
  const defaultOptions = [
    { value: "1", text: "Not Identified" },
    { value: "2", text: "Closed" },
    { value: "3", text: "Communicated" },
    { value: "4", text: "Identified" },
    { value: "5", text: "Resolved" },
    { value: "6", text: "Cancelled" }
  ];


  const { Option } = AutoComplete;



  return (
    <div>

      <AutoComplete
        open={dropdownOpen}
        style={{ width: 200 }}
        placeholder="Search..."
        listHeight={128}
        onChange={changeHandler}
        value={selectedOption}
      >
        {options.map((option) => (
          <Option key={option.value} value={option.text}>
            {option.text}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </AutoComplete>
      <Button
        disabled={!selectedValue}
        onClick={onClear}
        type="primary"
        icon={<CloseOutlined />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<EventsSection />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/customized-antd4153-alpha0-forked-iuh95?file=/index.js:968-1255) that I modified it from the official example, there are solutions for your questions.

1. how to display scrollbar always

you can use css-in-js such as `styled-components` or general css|scss approach to override dropdown styles.

```
.rc-virtual-list-scrollbar {
  display: block !important;
}
```

2. how to display full item list in dropdown menu

what version of antd are you useing? `listHeight="100%"` is work with v4.15.3

```
<AutoComplete
  style={{
    width: 200
  }}
  onSearch={handleSearch}
  placeholder="input here"
  listHeight="100%"
>
  {result.map((email) => (
    <Option key={email} value={email}>
      {email}
    </Option>
  ))}
</AutoComplete>
```

Comment: as you can see from example it is going on the input itself(cannot see input anymore), is it possible to have height of the page, if there is more content which overflows the page then there can be scrollbar (scrolling functionality when content is more than height of the page), but it should not cover input, input should be visible , dropdown should come under input like normally

Comment: in this case, you must check whether the listHeight exceeds the page height, if it exceeds, you cannot set listHeight="100%"